# Does MongoDB's Map/Reduce sort work?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

If the following is used

```
Analytic.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, 
  :query => {:page => subclass_name}, 
  :sort => [[:pageviews, Mongo::DESCENDING]]).find.to_a
```

it won't sort by `pageviews`.  Alternatively, if it is array of hash:

```
Analytic.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, 
  :query => {:page => subclass_name}, 
  :sort => [{:pageviews => Mongo::DESCENDING}]).find.to_a
```

it won't work either.  I think the reason it has to be an array is to specify the first field to sort by, etc.  I also tried just a flat array instead of an array of array like in the first code listing up above and it didn't work either.

Is it not working?  This is the spec: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#map_reduce-instance_method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you trying to do?  Sort is really only useful in conjunction with limit: it's applied before the map so you can just MapReduce the latest 20 items or something.  If you're trying to sort the results, you can just do a normal sort on the output collection.

Comment: i see.  maybe the spec can mention it is before the map, not for the final results.  also, why do we need to sort something for the map/reduce?  In cases I see the usage of map/reduce, it doesn't matter what order the documents (records) are in.

Comment: It's for aggregating a subset of your data.  Say you wanted to do an aggregation on the last 500 visits to your site.  You could do a MapReduce on your visitors collection with a sort by date and a limit of 500.  Without sort, you couldn't really do this.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it is a little bit tricky:

After the `map_reduce()`, a `Mongo::Collection` object is returned, but the structure is like:

```
[{"_id":123.0,"value":{"pageviews":3621.0,"timeOnPage":206024.0}},
 {"_id":1320.0,"value":{"pageviews":6584.0,"timeOnPage":373195.0}},
   ...
]
```

so to do the sort, it has to be:

```
Analytic.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, 
  :query => {:page => subclass_name}).find({}, 
    :sort => [['value.pageviews', Mongo::DESCENDING]])
```

note the `value.pageviews` part.

Comment: Is this true?  The documentation seems to indicate that the sort is applied to the collection you're mapping over before the mapper begins.  I don't see a way to sort the results, but I'm very curious to know if it can be done.